# Generating a logarithmic float range

Tags: python, numpy, recursion

I have some data that I am trying to analyse over a logarithmic range `0 < r < 1`. However, I want to be able to subdivide the range.

For example, I want to be able to produce a list such as `[1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0.005, 0.001, ..., 1e-10]`, but with the possibility of extending it further and subdividing it more.

I have looked to see if there is anything in NumPy to do this but could not find anything to do the job. I have also attempted to write a recursive function to achieve this goal, but I am pretty bad at recursion and am unable to get it to work.

I have also run into the issue that I cannot get the power of exponents into a function. For example:

```py
def exponent(num):
    return 1e-num
```

returns a `SyntaxError: invalid token`. This has not helped my attempts at getting the function to work.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think [`np.geomspace`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want such an array, `np.geomspace` is the way to go:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.geomspace(1E-10, 1, num=11)
>>> np.sort(np.r_[a, a / 2])[::-1]
array([1.e+00, 5.e-01, 1.e-01, 5.e-02, 1.e-02, 5.e-03, 1.e-03, 5.e-04,
       1.e-04, 5.e-05, 1.e-05, 5.e-06, 1.e-06, 5.e-07, 1.e-07, 5.e-08,
       1.e-08, 5.e-09, 1.e-09, 5.e-10, 1.e-10, 5.e-11])
```

`np.geomspace(1E-10, 1, num=11)` creates `array([1, 1e-1, ..., 1e-10])`, then I concatenate it with `a/2`, finally sort it to get your result.

A bit nicer solution from [Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988730/mad-physicist), which avoids sorting:

```py
np.stack((a, a / 2), axis=-1).ravel()
```

Comment: There is really no need to sort (just stack along axis=-1 and flatten), but this is the right way to go.

Comment: Specifically, `a = np.geomspace(1, 1e-10, 11); np.stack((a, a / 2), axis=-1).ravel()`